# jQuery Cookies with multiple classed div boxes

Tags: jquery, css, class, html, cookies

What I have at the moment an achievement site, where users can view achievements (stored in div boxes all styled with **.unselect**) and then change to the style **.select** when clicked on using jQuery. This also adds a count to the top right of the page so users can see how many they have selected.

What I'm trying to do now is make those selected boxes be remembered through cookies, so that when the user reloads or comes back to the page, the boxes they selected earlier still remain there, along with the number count.

I've been attempting all day and night to try and get this working, and looking around on here all the answers to fix it are for hiding div classes, rather than simply changing the style, and my attempts to modify them have pretty much failed.

Here's an shortened version of  section of the HTML I've written so far:

```
<body>

    <div id="header">
        <h1>Header Title here</h1>
        <p class="navigation">Some navigation links</p>
    </div>

    <div id="counter">
        <h1>Counted:</h1>
        <p class="numCount">0</p>
    </div>

    <div id="container">

        <h2>Plus Achievements</h2>

        <div class="unselect">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
                <tr>
                    <td width="64" valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1733724/tf2icons/tf_complete_training.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" align="left">
                        <h3>Title Here</h3>
                        <p>Description Here</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

        <div class="unselect">
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="6">
                <tr>
                    <td width="64" valign="middle">
                        <img src="http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1733724/tf2icons/tf_complete_training.png"/>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" align="left">
                        <h3>Title Here</h3>
                        <p>Description Here</p>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>



        <script>

            $(".unselect").click(function() {
                $(this).toggleClass("select");

                var numSelect = $('.select').length
                $('#counter').html('<h1>Counted:</h1><p class="numCount">' + numSelect + '</p>');
            });

        </script>

</body>

</html>
```

You can access the document I use to style the page here:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1733724/cgl-pascal.css

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to simplify, use [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) and the rest should be easy.

Here's a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/unloco/5AxV2/2/)
you have to add specific IDs to each of the divs

```
<div class="unselect" id="div1"></div>
<div class="unselect" id="div2"></div>
...


var selectedDivs = $.cookie("selected");//get the cookie
if(selectedDivs){
    var IDs = selectedDivs.split(' '); //split by space and get array of IDs
    for(i=0;i<IDs.length;i++){
     var ID = IDs[i];
     if(ID) $('.unselect'+ID).toggleClass("select"); //select only the specific ID            
    }
    $('#counter').html('<h1>Counted:</h1><p class="numCount">' +    $('.select').length + '</p>');
}
```

then you should add to the handler

```
 var selectedDivs = "";
 $('div.select').each(function(){
     selectedDivs += " #" + $(this).attr('id');//add the ID with a space
 });
 $.cookie("selected",selectedDivs, { expires: 30 }); //store all selected IDs
```